# Express listen is not working and port is taken from env automatically

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jestjs

After writing all the endpoints I decided to add PORTS and JWT_key to .ENV by using dotenv package all work perfectly fine until I decided to do Integration testing now express.listen is not working and it automatically takes the port from .ENV file and I don't how

this is app.js

```
require("express-async-errors");
const Express = require("express");
const app= Express();
const winston = require("winston");
require("./start/logger")();
require("./start/routes")(express);
require("./start/db")();
require("./start/config")();
require("dotenv").config();

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const server = app.listen(port, () =>
  console.log(`listening on port ${port}`)
);

module.exports = server;
```

gets nothing on the console

this is .env file

```
PORT=9000
jwtPrivateKey="myPrivateKey"
```

as soon as I remove the port from .env file the server stop responding

this is my test file

```
const request = require("supertest");

let server;

describe("/api/genres", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    server = require("../../app");
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    server.close();
  });

  describe("GET /", () => {
    it("should return all genres", async () => {
      jest.setTimeout(2000);
      const res = await request(server).get("/api/genres");
      expect(res.status).toBe(200);
    });
  });
});
```

please guide me through this I did not make a git repo for this otherwise I would have reset it

Comment: If `express = require("express")`, then `express.listen` is not a function. You mean `app = express(); app.listen(...);`, right?

Comment: sorry, I didn't add my imports but no in my code express=app check the imports

Answer (score 1):

In your .env file change the variables from

```
port=9000
```

to

```
PORT=9000
```

You are getting the error because the variables inside of your .env are not in capital however in your code you're using `process.env.PORT` where they are in capitals.

Following on from what Heiko has said, it is good convention to use `app` instead of `express`. I would change the top of the code to:

```js
const Express = require("express");
const app = Express();
```

And then change the `express.listen()` to:

```js
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, () =>
  console.log(`listening on port ${port}`)
);
```

Thanks! I hope this helps.

Comment: well, I test all possible ways to change the name to PORT or port or Port before asking question I don't what happens to the code but this app.listen is not working and it takes port from env file for some reason

Comment: @Dexter Sorry would you be able to explain that again, would you like the server to take the port from your `.env` file or do you want it to take the `5000` that is set inside of the code?

Comment: see currently I want to test an endpoint for which I need a server object which is given by this app.listen but even if I delete this app.listen fn the server still runs as it takes port from the env file..  that is my point why is it taking PORT from env when I delete app.listen fn from app.js